# SQL String Column - Looking for any integers inside parenthesis in a String

Tags: sql, ssms, where-clause

I'm trying to list only the entries that contain an Integer inside a parenthesis in a String Column.

For example, I have this three entries in a Column, let's Call the Column "Description" in the Table "Recipes":

Entry 1: Nr 2021-008/10. AZ (123) 
Entry 2: Nr (part) 2021-009/10. AZ 
Entry 3: Nr 2021-011/10. AZ (418)

In this case, I'd like only Entry 1 and Entry 3 to be listed. 
How would the where clause look like here? Im using SSMS.

Select Description from dbo.Recipes 
where ... ?

Thanks in andvance for any help and /or tips.

Comment: Is the number of digits in the integer always 3?  Does it always appear at the end of the value?

Comment: the number of digits is variable and it can appear anywhere in the String... but your query worked just fine... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might able to just use `PATINDEX` here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    PATINDEX('%([0-9]%', entry) > 0 AND PATINDEX('%[0-9])%', entry) > 0 AND
    PATINDEX('%[0-9])%', entry) > PATINDEX('%([0-9]%', entry);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Keep in mind that this targets any string that has ( followed by an integer with an integer followed by ) later in the string.  Which is fine for the example data the the OP is showing but if say the value was Nr 2021-011/10. AZ (4) 1a8) it would still be returned.

Comment: @Bee_Riii Without regex, this is the best I can do.

Comment: not a criticism.  Just want the OP to understand the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to make this work.

```
SELECT myColumn FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE '%([0-9])%'
```

Comment: This would target things like `(1)` and `(9)`, but not more than one digit in parentheses.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think this is correct. It sounds that [0-9]* will not work either

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMairegger... I've tried that as well, but unfortunately the number of digits is always more than one... :-)